# Quartz scheduler 7 days before end of the month

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler

I would like to configure my quartz scheduler to run on the seventh day before the end of the month.
I managed to set up the last day of each month (0 0 0 L * ? *), but could not catch the seventh day before.
Ex: The script must run in 24/10/12, 23/11/12, 24/12/12, 24/01/13, 21/02/13 ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty close:

```
0 0 0 L-7 * ? *
```

Notice the `"-7"` part. I tested this with Quartz 2.1.5, this feature was implemented as part of [QTZ-91](https://jira.terracotta.org/jira/browse/QTZ-91).

Comment: Tankhs.
I tried this, but the website cronmaker says that expression is invalid...

Comment: @user1754313: it might be Quartz-specific, I know it works from 2.0+.

Comment: Ok, my version of Quartz is 1.8.4. I will update and try again. Many thanks for the help Tomasz.